# Optimizing a logic AND operation for x86

Tags: gcc, optimization, x86, simd, bitmask

I am trying to optimize an algorithm that masks an array. The initial code looks like this:

```
void mask(unsigned int size_x, unsigned int size_y, uint32_t *source, uint32_t *m)
{
    unsigned int rep=size_x*size_y;
    while (rep--)
    {            
        *(source++) &= *(m++);
    }
}
```

I have tried to do Loop Unrolling + prefetching

```
void mask_LU4(unsigned int size_x, unsigned int size_y, uint32_t *source, uint32_t   *mask)
{                             // in place
    unsigned int rep;
    rep= size_x* size_y;
    rep/= 4 ; 
    while (rep--) 
    {              
        _mm_prefetch(&source[16], _MM_HINT_T0);
        _mm_prefetch(&mask[16], _MM_HINT_T0);
        source[0] &= mask[0];
        source[1] &= mask[1];
        source[2] &= mask[2];
        source[3] &= mask[3];
        source += 4;
        mask += 4;
    }
}
```

and use intrinsics

```
void fmask_SIMD(unsigned int size_x, unsigned int size_y, uint32_t *source, uint32_t *mask)
{                             // in place
    unsigned int rep;
    __m128i *s,*m ;
    s = (__m128i *) source;
    m = (__m128i *) mask;
    rep= size_x* size_y;
    rep/= 4 ; 
    while (rep--) 
    {               
        *s = _mm_and_si128(*s,*m);
        source+=4;mask+=4; 
        s = (__m128i *) source;
        m = (__m128i *) mask;
    }   
}
```

However the performance is the same. I have tried to perform sw prefetch both to the SIMD and Loop Unrolling version and it I couldn't see any improvement. Any ideas on how I could optimize this algorithm?

P.S.1: I am using gcc 4.8.1 and I compile with `-march=native` and `-Ofast`.

P.S.2: I am using an Intel Core i5 3470 @3.2Ghz, Ivy bridge architecture. L1 DCache 4X32KB (8-way), L2 4x256, L3 6MB, RAM-DDR3 4Gb (Dual Channel, DRAM @798,1Mhz)

Comment: I suspect the arrays are large enough that you're actually measuring memory bandwidth. There's nothing you can do about that, except "not doing it".

Comment: Don't new CPUs do automatic preloads?

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE even old ones do by now

Comment: The input size is 19MB. Compiler can perform automatic preloads (sw prefetch) but according to my experience especially in embedded platforms, manual preloading is more efficient.

Comment: @harold is correct. This is memory bandwidth bound. And since source and destination are the same stream instructions won't help. But you can use multiple threads. Contrary to what many people think a single thread does not saturate the main memory bandwidth.

Comment: You can try `#pragma omp parallel for` newline `for(int i=0; i<rep; i++) { source[i] &= m[i]; }`

Comment: @Zboson,I tried to Run some memory bandwidth tests. I wrote three functions that initialize an integer array of 19MB. So i am just writing to the array. The 1st version is a the simplest (Repeat: array[i]=1) , In the second one i am using _mm256_store_si256 and in the 3rd one _mm256_stream_si256. The results are : 7.38, 7.96 and 17.05 GB/sec. While the Memory bandwidth of the mask algorithm is  16.52GB/s.

Comment: @Zboson, So my questions are: 1) That means I can go beyond the 16.52GB/s ?? Or not because in the mask algorithm i can't use streaming instructions? 2) The theoretical bandwidth of my RAM is 798MHZ*2channels*2interfaces*64bit =... = 25.536GB/s. According to wiki we cannot reach this maximum bandwidth. So how can I understand if it is worth improving my mask algorithm?

Comment: @Nick, can you please state your hardware? Also what wiki are you refering to where you say "According to wiki we cannot reach this maximum bandwidth." ?

Comment: @Zboson, I updated my initial post with a 2nd P.S. The wiki page is : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_bandwidth (look at Bandwidth computation and nomenclature for calculating theoretical Memory Bandwidth)

Comment: @Zboson, Wiki says : " . In practice the observed memory bandwidth will be less than (and is guaranteed not to exceed) the advertised bandwidth." .

Comment: @Nick, your CPU has four physical cores. If you want to get closer to the maximum bandwidth then use multiple threads as I suggested.

Comment: Before using intrinsics and such, did you check the generated code? It was most likely already vectorized.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Of course, I checked. It wasn't vectorized although -Ofast enables autovectorization. From my experience autovectorization does not work well!

Comment: @Nick Well, it was vectorized when I tried it...

Comment: @MarcGlisse You are right, I am sorry. However the code generated for fmask_simple is different than the one generated for fmask_SIMD. The latter has a loop with 8 instructions while the former a loop with 11.  I think that trying to use intrinsics many times you can produce better (i mean less) SIMD assembly instructions. Please let me know if you disagree.

Comment: With a recent gcc, the auto-vectorized loop is just 7 instructions. In your simd version, you are assuming that the arrays are 128-bit aligned, which is kind of cheating: either it is wrong, or you could tell it to the compiler with __builtin_assume_aligned to help optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

Your operation is memory bandwidth bound. However, that does not necessarily mean your operation is achieving the maximum memory bandwidth.  To get closer to the maximum memory bandwidth you need to use multiple threads. Using OpenMP (add `-fopenmp` to GCC's options) you can do this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0; i<rep; i++) { source[i] &= m[i]; }
```

If you wanted to not modify the source but use a different destination then you can use stream instructions like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0; i<rep/4; i++) {
    __m128i m4 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)&m[4*i]);
    __m128i s4 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)&source[4*i]);
    s4 = _mm_and_si128(s4,m4);
    _mm_stream_si128((__m128i*i)&dest[4*i], s4);
}
```

This would not be any faster than using the same destination and source. However, if you already planned to use a destination not equal to the source this would likely be faster (for some value of `rep`) than using `_mm_store_si128`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I have tried to apply streaming instructions, using a different destination without multithreading and there was no difference. Unfortunately for my project multiple threads is not an option. 

However I have one question: How can I verify that my mask algorithm is memory bandwidth bound? Can I use a profiler for this? And if yes, could you please suggest one?

Comment: @Nick, what is your hardware? What exactly is the CPU you are using?

Comment: @Nick, your algorithm is memory bandwidth bound because the CPU is much faster than main memory and you don't reuse data. The best solution to your problem is to not do this as Harold said. Change your algorithm. Don't process the whole array all at once. Do it in chunks along with other calculations.

Comment: @Nick, but if you must to it then you should find the theoretic max bandwidth of your hardware and then compare that to the bandwidth you measure. This can tell you how much you _might_ be able to gain with a lot of effort.

Comment: @Nick, your algorithm is doing two integer reads and one integer write so your measured bandwidth is `3*sizeof(int)*rep/time`.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem might be memory bound, but that does not mean you cannot process more per cycle. Usually when you have a low payload operation (like yous here, it's only an AND after all), it makes sense to combine many loads and stores. In most CPUs most loads will be combined by the L2 cache into a single cache line load (especially if they're consecutive). I'd suggest increasing the loop unrolling to at least 4 SIMD packets here, along with the prefetching. You'd still be memory bound, but you will get fewer cache misses, giving you a slightly better performance.

Comment: Unrolling in the source (or in compiler-generated asm which is a separate matter) reduces loop overhead, but has very little to do with whether HW prefetch can keep up or not.  Modern x86 CPUs have OoO execution to hide load latency, so you don't particularly need to do software pipelining to load far ahead of stores that use the result.  There aren't enough registers to make a meaningful difference, and compilers can already do that when unrolling.  Loads interleaved with stores doesn't create extra cache misses.